# Power shell Script execution from the AD on the all domain joined machines

Tags: active-directory, powershell-2.0

I have written a power shell script for downloading and executing the binary file that I want to deploy on more than 500 machines. I have already an active directory configured and all the machines in my network are on the domain.
Some can please tell me that how I can execute this power shell script on the domain connected machines from the active directory like we deploy an MSI file from the AD.

Thanks

Comment: Configure it as a startup or logon script, dending on whether it needs to run in the system's or the user's context.

Comment: I am new to AD, what I know is I want to run it on the computer. Can you please elaborate the steps needed

Comment: What I have tried before is, converted the power shell script to exe and from exe to MSI using some freely available tools and tried to execute the MSI package, but it is not working ...

Comment: If you want to deploy an MSI package you can use Group Policy to perform the operation: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-gpo.html

Comment: $user=$env:username
$localIpAddress=((ipconfig | findstr [0-9].\.)[0]).Split()[-1]
powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://192.168.10.220/$localIpAddress.exe','C:\Users\$user\Downloads\ossec.exe')" 
cd  "C:\Users\$user\Downloads"
 .\ossec.exe /S

Comment: Here is the script i want to run as startup 
'$user=$env:username
$localIpAddress=((ipconfig | findstr [0-9].\.)[0]).Split()[-1]
powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://192.168.10.220/$localIpAddress.exe','C:\Users\$user\Downloads\ossec.exe')" 
cd  "C:\Users\$user\Downloads"
.\ossec.exe /S'

Comment: I have tested this script on windows seven 7 and it's working, downloading the binary file and also install it silently but when I tried to run it as a start up script from   the active directory it is not working. Can somebody please explain what's the problem with this script.

Comment: Startup script runs under Local System account (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770556(v=ws.11).aspx). Maybe using environment variable $env:username is a problem. What I recommend is to run your script under Local System account with detailed logging to a file. To to this you need to create a scheduled task that will run your script as described here: http://superuser.com/questions/347751/how-can-i-run-a-scheduled-task-as-system, and modify the script of course. Thus you will not need to restart computer every time after you modify the script. Run the scheduled task manually.

Comment: My guess is that the folder C:\Users\$user‌​\Downloads does not exist for Local System account and the script stops executing